# How to simulate entering input text within reac-select creatable using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, capybara, react-select

I've used react-select AsyncCreatable to make Search Prompt for records. Now I want to write some integration tests for it using Capybara. I don't know how to do it though. I've tried clicking the element and telling capybara to `fill_in('node', with: 'text')` but no luck actually.

I'm using `Selenium` with `:headless_chrome`.
I'm getting a `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable`

I've also tried set `find('#people_search_form_name').set('Vini')`. That didn't break, but didn't add the text to the input field.

Does anyone have any tip on how to achieve it?

Here's the html generated

```
<div class=" css-dyr6gj-container" id="people_search_form_name">
  <div class="people_search_form_name__control css-yk16xz-control">
    <div class="people_search_form_name__value-container css-g1d714-ValueContainer">
      <div class="people_search_form_name__placeholder css-1wa3eu0-placeholder">Find people</div>
        <div class="css-b8ldur-Input">
          <div class="people_search_form_name__input" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="react-select-3-input" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-label="Find people" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: 0px center; border: 0px; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 12.8px; font-family: FiraSans, -apple-system, system-ui, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, &quot;Noto Sans&quot;, sans-serif, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;, &quot;Noto Color Emoji&quot;; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="people_search_form_name__indicators css-1hb7zxy-IndicatorsContainer">
      </div>
    </div>
  <input name="people_search_form[name]" type="hidden" value="">
</div>
```

I've learned one way to achieve this is by using `send_keys`. Something like

```
      find('.addresses_search_form_name__input').send_keys('Margate road')
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work either.

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
```

(Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.121)

Comment: Interact with each field exactly as a user would. If the user hast to click an element then click it, etc. if you need more help than that you’ll need to add the exact HTML you’re dealing with to your question

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I've added the html input. I've tried clicking it and seems to be ok. Tricky part seems to be filling it. I've tried `fill_in` on a few of those selectors. For instance Minitest::UnexpectedError: Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "addresses_search_form_name__control" that is not disabled

Comment: you’re talking about address search forms but added HTML for people search so it’s unclear exactly what you’re doing

Comment: @ThomasWalpole apologies . the form is dynamic and will change depending on the search type. I was with the default open (people) when I copied the markup. For the sake of conversation let's consider it a people search

Comment: So you need to click on whatever the user would click on and then look at whatever HTML is dynamically generated and interact with those elements the same way a user would

Comment: Cool. I think I managed to get it working by doing that. I've clicked on `__control` element to focus and sent keys to the react generated input `#react-select-3-input` and it worked. Looks hacky as that react id is quite random. but it works.